# Url is Changing but Requested Page is not Loading in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

My App Component is here

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Navbar from './components/layout/Navbar';
import Landing from './components/layout/Landing';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Login from './components/auth/Login';
import Register from './components/auth/Register';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './store';
import Alert from './components/layout/Alert';
import setAuthToken from './utils/setAuthToken';
import { loadUser } from './actions/auth';
import Dashboard from './components/dashboard/Dashboard';
import PrivateRoute from './components/routing/PrivateRoute';
import CreateProfile from './components/profile-form/CreateProfile';
import EditProfile from './components/profile-form/EditProfile';
import AddExperience from './components/profile-form/AddExperience';
import AddEducation from './components/profile-form/AddEducation';

if (localStorage.token) {
  setAuthToken(localStorage.token);
}

const App = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    store.dispatch(loadUser());
  }, []);
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router>
        <>
          <Navbar />
          <Route exact path='/' component={Landing} />
          <section className='container'>
            <Alert />
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path='/login' component={Login} />
              <Route exact path='/register' component={Register} />
              <PrivateRoute exact path='/dashboard' component={Dashboard} />
              <PrivateRoute
                exact
                path='/create-profile'
                component={CreateProfile}
              />
              <PrivateRoute
                exact
                path='/edit-profile'
                component={EditProfile}
              />
              <PrivateRoute
                exact
                to='/add-experience'
                component={AddExperience}
              />
              <PrivateRoute
                exact
                path='/add-education'
                component={AddEducation}
              />
            </Switch>
          </section>
        </>
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

My AddExperience Component is here

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { addExperience } from '../../actions/profile';
import { Link, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const AddExperience = ({ addExperience, history }) => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    company: '',
    title: '',
    location: '',
    from: '',
    to: '',
    current: false,
    description: '',
  });
  const [toDateDisabled, toggleDisabled] = useState(false);
  const { company, title, location, from, to, current, description } = formData;

  const onChange = (e) => {
    setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <h1 className='large text-primary'>Add An Experience</h1>
      <p className='lead'>
        <i className='fas fa-code-branch'></i> Add any developer/programming
        positions that you have had in the past
      </p>
      <small>* = required field</small>
      <form
        className='form'
        onSubmit={(e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
          addExperience(formData, history);
        }}
      >
        <div className='form-group'>
          <input
            type='text'
            placeholder='* Job Title'
            name='title'
            value={title}
            onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
            required
          />
        </div>
        <div className='form-group'>
          <input
            type='text'
            placeholder='* Company'
            name='company'
            value={company}
            onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
            required
          />
        </div>
        <div className='form-group'>
          <input
            type='text'
            placeholder='Location'
            name='location'
            value={location}
            onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
          />
        </div>
        <div className='form-group'>
          <h4>From Date</h4>
          <input
            type='date'
            name='from'
            value={from}
            onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
          />
        </div>
        <div className='form-group'>
          <p>
            <input
              type='checkbox'
              name='current'
              checked={current}
              value={current}
              onChange={(e) => {
                setFormData({ ...formData, current: !current });
                toggleDisabled(!toDateDisabled);
              }}
            />{' '}
            Current Job
          </p>
        </div>
        <div className='form-group'>
          <h4>To Date</h4>
          <input
            type='date'
            name='to'
            value={to}
            onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
            disabled={toDateDisabled ? 'disable' : ''}
          />
        </div>
        <div className='form-group'>
          <textarea
            name='description'
            cols='30'
            rows='5'
            placeholder='Job Description'
            value={description}
            onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
          ></textarea>
        </div>
        <input type='submit' className='btn btn-primary my-1' />
        <a className='btn btn-light my-1' href='dashboard.html'>
          Go Back
        </a>
      </form>
    </>
  );
};

AddExperience.propTypes = {
  addExperience: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

export default connect(null, { addExperience })(AddExperience);
```

Here is my AddEducation Component

```
import React, { useState, Fragment } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { addEducation } from '../../actions/profile';
import { Link, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const AddEducation = ({ addEducation, history }) => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    school: '',
    degree: '',
    fieldofstudy: '',
    from: '',
    to: '',
    current: false,
    description: '',
  });
  const [toDateDisabled, toggleDisabled] = useState(false);
  const {
    school,
    degree,
    fieldofstudy,
    from,
    to,
    current,
    description,
  } = formData;

  const onChange = (e) => {
    setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <h1 className='large text-primary'>Add Your Education</h1>
      <p className='lead'>
        <i className='fas fa-code-branch'></i> Add any School or bootcamp that
        you have attended
      </p>
      <small>* = required field</small>
      <form
        className='form'
        onSubmit={(e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
          addEducation(formData, history);
        }}
      >
        <div className='form-group'>
          <input
            type='text'
            placeholder='* School or Bootcamp'
            name='school'
            value={school}
            onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
            required
          />
        </div>
        <div className='form-group'>
          <input
            type='text'
            placeholder='* Degree or Certificate'
            name='degree'
            value={degree}
            onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
            required
          />
        </div>
        <div className='form-group'>
          <input
            type='text'
            placeholder='fieldofstudy'
            name='fieldofstudy'
            value={fieldofstudy}
            onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
          />
        </div>
        <div className='form-group'>
          <h4>From Date</h4>
          <input
            type='date'
            name='from'
            value={from}
            onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
          />
        </div>
        <div className='form-group'>
          <p>
            <input
              type='checkbox'
              name='current'
              checked={current}
              value={current}
              onChange={(e) => {
                setFormData({ ...formData, current: !current });
                toggleDisabled(!toDateDisabled);
              }}
            />{' '}
            Current Job
          </p>
        </div>
        <div className='form-group'>
          <h4>To Date</h4>
          <input
            type='date'
            name='to'
            value={to}
            onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
            disabled={toDateDisabled ? 'disable' : ''}
          />
        </div>
        <div className='form-group'>
          <textarea
            name='description'
            cols='30'
            rows='5'
            placeholder='Programme Description'
            value={description}
            onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
          ></textarea>
        </div>
        <input type='submit' className='btn btn-primary my-1' />
        <a className='btn btn-light my-1' href='dashboard.html'>
          Go Back
        </a>
      </form>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

AddEducation.propTypes = {
  addEducation: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

export default connect(null, { addEducation })(AddEducation);
```

And Lastly here is the DashboardActions Component

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const DashboardActions = () => {
  return (
    <div className='dash-buttons'>
      <Link to='/edit-profile' className='btn btn-light'>
        <i className='fas fa-user-circle text-primary' /> Edit Profile
      </Link>
      <Link to='/add-experience' className='btn btn-light'>
        <i className='fab fa-black-tie text-primary' /> Add Experience
      </Link>
      <Link to='/add-education' className='btn btn-light'>
        <i className='fas fa-graduation-cap text-primary' /> Add Education
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
};

export default DashboardActions;
```

The Problem is When i Click on AddExperience it opens correctly with correct url but when i click on AddEducation it Opens the same Add Experience Form but url changed Correctly.

Comment: may be some issue will be in your Private Route File. Make sure you are mapping the correct component with the route.

Comment: Are you getting no errors in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo here:

```
<PrivateRoute
     exact
     to='/add-experience'
     component={AddExperience} 
  />
```

The 'to' should be replaced with 'path'